# QML TextArea breaks down on changing text inside onTextChanged

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, recursion, qml

Working with TextArea, I had a need to do syntax highlighting using regular expressions. Everything was fine until the program started to crash from an error:

> pure virtual method called
> terminate called without an active exception

Having studied the problem in detail, I came to some conclusions that may help in the answer:

In this example, the code never reaches test, and a huge recursion occurs

```js
onTextChanged: {
    text = "35" -> fall there

    console.log("test") 
}
```

Next, I fixed this problem and everything works fine, without recursion

```js
onTextChanged: {
    if(!processing) {
        processing = true
        text = "35"
    }
    processing = false
    console.log("test")
}
```

But I need to work with the original text, and when I try to add something to it, or use it, everything falls with the errors indicated above

```js
onTextChanged: {
    if(!processing) {
        processing = true
        (text = text + " word") or just (text = text)
    }
    processing = false
    console.log("test") -> fall after there, maybe in destructor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to a key release signal to reset the processing flag. Here is a basic example:

```
TextArea {
    property bool processing: false

    onTextChanged: {
        if (!processing) {
            processing = true
            text = text + "word"
        }
    }

    Keys.onReleased: {
        processing = false
    }
}
```